# Giving a function within a class method of a PrototypeJS Class access to class members

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypejs

Let's say I have a very simple PrototypeJS class that looks like this:

```
var Foo = Class.create({
  initialize:  function() {
    this.bar = 'bar';
  },

  dostuff:  function() {
    $$('.enabled').each( function(elem) {
      alert(this.bar);  //FAIL
    });
  }
});
```

This fails because the function being passed to **.each()** doesn't have any idea what *this* refers to.

How can I access the **bar** attribute of the Class from inside that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Prototype's bind function](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind), which 'locks [the function's] execution scope to an object'.

```
var Foo = Class.create({
  initialize:  function() {
    this.bar = 'bar';
  },

  dostuff:  function() {
    $$('.enabled').each( function(elem) {
      alert(this.bar);
    }.bind(this)); // Set the execution scope to Foo
  }
});
```

Comment: bind() seems to be slightly an overkill since each() already takes a second parameter, which is the execution scope.

Comment: Maybe Mark's original example isn't a good one then since it is a call to Enumerable.each which does allow you to specify scope. However, since the title of the question asks how to give *a function* access to class members I think Function.bind is more appropriate.

Comment: This example probably is a bit simple for bind() but I accepted this answer because I see bind() as having more long-term utility for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
dostuff:  function() {
   var that = this;

   $$('.enabled').each( function(elem) {
        alert(that.bar);  //FTW
   });
}
```

Or, pass a context to `each()`:

```
dostuff:  function() {
   $$('.enabled').each( function(elem) {
        alert(this.bar);  //FTW
   }, this); // Context
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I'm no Protoype expert, but I *think* this might help answer your question - http://www.duncangunn.me.uk/dasblog/2009/05/26/ObjectorientedEventHandlingInJavascript.aspx

Let me know if it does, if it doesn't, apologies for wasting your time!

Answer (score 0):

When you're inside the each(), *this* refers to what's being iterated with each. If there's only one instance of the class, replace all this's with Foo.

```
var Foo = Class.create({
bar : "bar",

  dostuff:  function() {
    $$('.enabled').each( function(elem) {
      alert(Foo.bar);  //FAIL
    });
  }
});
```

if you can't get away with alert(bar);